# what are upcoming/current new techonology in perl will be used in enterprise applications

Tags: perl

I have want to keep update the latest techonology and understand and learn the new tech in perl which used in enterprise applications ?

Comment: This question can't be answered constructively and is too localised (what is "latest" now won't be in the future). Read Perl blogs if you want to an idea about what things in Perl-land are gaining traction.

Comment: Just keep track of topics that appear under `perl` tag here on SO, and follow links to documentation/explanations (probably with depth=2, i.e. including links at linked pages).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps @Quentin is right and "latest" will change, but the enterprise moves slowly. This question could be relevant from 2012-2017 quite easily.

What would I like to see if being shown around during an interview?

- Access to CPAN (otherwise why use Perl?)
- Good test suites through Test::More and friends
- Probably some continuous-integration using jenkins or some such
- Use of local::lib to manage different versions of libraries
- Use of perlbrew to manage different versions of perl
- Moose (or maybe Moo) for objects
- Try::Tiny or similar exception handling
- Perhaps Exception::Class or friends for structured exceptions
- Log::Any or some other standardised logging interface
- Some standards regarding documentation, perltidy, perlcritic

A lot of that is more to do with procedures than technology, but then a lot of the effort in producing good, maintainable, reliable code and deploying it is in the procedures.

[Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/) though is probably about as "latest" an object system as any language has. Almost everything else mentioned above can be found through cpan, apart from [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) which is a java app.